# Running FedUtil.exe silently

Tags: asp.net, adfs, federated-identity

Is it possible to run FedUtil.exe silently on RP machine in order to establish a trust with an STS? instead of using the UI

FedUtil screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzo7E.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can run FedUtil in the command prompt.

I don't have a VS 2010 installation any more but IIRC it was part of the WIF install.

The problem is that it uses WIF (which still works) but you miss all the new OWIN goodness!